# How can i add a new tab in left in sales order view,like now are invoices credit memos,releases etc in magento

Tags: magento

i want to add a new tab in left in sales->order->view.For this i have created a module but not solved my problem,it is showing an error like wrong tab configuration,i have search on many links also posted in stack overflow,but not yet satisfied.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This actually should be quite easy to do. Just look at the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml` layout file. You can find there the `<adminhtml_sales_order_view>` node, which defines all blocks used on order's view page.

In order to add a new tab, you would need to put another `<action`> declaration in the file. Currently tabs are defined like this (Magento EE 1.11):

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    (...)
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>order_info</name><block>order_tab_info</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>order_invoices</name><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_invoices</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>order_creditmemos</name><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_creditmemos</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>order_shipments</name><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_shipments</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>order_history</name><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_history</block></action>
            <action method="addTab"><name>order_transactions</name><block>adminhtml/sales_order_view_tab_transactions</block></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Be aware, **do not change core templates!**

In this case you should create new module or alter existing one in **local** code pool. Define a layout updates in `config.xml` and then create new layout file in adminhtml default theme, for example:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/CUSTOM_VENDOR/sales.xml`:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
        <action method="addTab"><name>TAB_NAME</name><block>CUSTOM_BLOCK</block></action>         
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Then you just need to create new block and a template.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. very useful. One question. I understood we should not modify the code/core/mage file, shouldn't we change design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml also?